# I'm working on a data cleaning task in R, I need assistance with concatenating values based on specific conditions. Here's the scenario

Tags: r

I want to concatenate the 'GID' values of the empty cells below a non-empty 'keep' until another non-empty 'keep' is encountered. If the keep value is empty, do nothing, and if it does not have an empty cell below it do noting as well.

```
 > dt <- tibble(
     GID = c(27841, 31479, 11458, 15096, 30447, 14064, 32289, 15906, 54701, 57564, 57916),
     gpid1 = c(11458, 15096, 0, 0, 14064, 0, 15906, 0, 1, 57548, 57548),
     gpid2 = c(11458, 15096, 0, 0, 14064, 0, 15906, 0, 5, 57526, 57526),
     nstat = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
     nval_new = c(-85239, -85239, -85239, -85239, -8835, -8835, -8732, -8732, 1, 1, 1),
     keep = c(27841, NA,NA, NA, 30447, NA, 32289, NA, 54701, NA, NA)
   )
```

This is what I want to achieve: I want the 'GID' values of the empty cells below a non-empty 'keep' cell to be concatenated in the merge column.

```
    # A tibble: 11 x 7
 GID gpid1 gpid2 nstat nval_new keep merges
 <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>
   27841 11458 11458     0   -85239    27841    31479; 11458; 15096
   31479 15096 15096     0   -85239       NA
   11458     0     0     1   -85239       NA
   15096     0     0     1   -85239       NA
   30447 14064 14064     0    -8835    30447    14064
   14064     0     0     1    -8835       NA
   32289 15906 15906     0    -8732    32289   15906
   15906     0     0     1    -8732       NA
   54701     1     5     1        1    54701
   57564 57548 57526     1        1       NA    57564; 57916
   57916 57548 57526     1        1       NA
```

I've tried the following code, but the 'merges' column is not giving the desired output:

```
 # Create a helper column 'group' to identify different 
  groups of non-empty 'keep' values
  cleaned_data <- cleaned_data %>%
  mutate(
    group = cumsum(!is.na(keep) & is.na(lead(keep)))
   )

 # Concatenate 'GID' values of the empty cells below non- 
empty 'keep' values
 cleaned_data <- cleaned_data %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(
     merges = ifelse(!is.na(keep), 
                     ifelse(any(is.na(lead(keep)) & 
 !is.na(lead(gid))), paste(lead(gid), collapse = "; "), ""), 
                     "")
   ) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   select(-group)
```

This is the output I got:

```
 # A tibble: 11 x 7
  GID gpid1 gpid2 nstat nval_new keep merges
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>
    27841 11458 11458     0   -85239    27841
    31479 15096 15096     0   -85239       NA
    11458     0     0     1   -85239       NA
    15096     0     0     1   -85239       NA
    30447 14064 14064     0    -8835    30447    
    14064     0     0     1    -8835       NA
    32289 15906 15906     0    -8732    32289
    15906     0     0     1    -8732       NA
    54701     1     5     1        1    54701
    57564 57548 57526     1        1       NA
    57916 57548 57526     1        1       NA
```

Can someone help me identify what's going wrong or provide a better approach to achieve this concatenation of 'GID' values based on the specified conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

dt %>% 
  mutate(group = keep) %>%  
  fill(group) %>%  
  mutate(merges = if_else(row_number() != 1, NA_character_, 
                          str_flatten(GID[!GID %in% keep], ", ")), 
         .by = group) %>% 
  select(!group)

# A tibble: 11 × 7
     GID gpid1 gpid2 nstat nval_new  keep merges             
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>              
 1 27841 11458 11458     0   -85239 27841 31479, 11458, 15096
 2 31479 15096 15096     0   -85239    NA NA                 
 3 11458     0     0     1   -85239    NA NA                 
 4 15096     0     0     1   -85239    NA NA                 
 5 30447 14064 14064     0    -8835 30447 14064              
 6 14064     0     0     1    -8835    NA NA                 
 7 32289 15906 15906     0    -8732 32289 15906              
 8 15906     0     0     1    -8732    NA NA                 
 9 54701     1     5     1        1 54701 57564, 57916       
10 57564 57548 57526     1        1    NA NA                 
11 57916 57548 57526     1        1    NA NA
```

Alternatively, if you are able to group by `nval_new`:

```
dt %>%  
  mutate(merges = if_else(row_number() != 1, NA_character_, 
                          str_flatten(GID[!GID %in% keep], ", ")), 
         .by = nval_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use merge function too. for e.g.,

```
library(dplyr)

# Define the data frame
dt <- tibble(
  GID = c(27841, 31479, 11458, 15096, 30447, 14064, 32289, 15906, 54701, 57564, 57916),
  gpid1 = c(11458, 15096, 0, 0, 14064, 0, 15906, 0, 1, 57548, 57548),
  gpid2 = c(11458, 15096, 0, 0, 14064, 0, 15906, 0, 5, 57526, 57526),
  nstat = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  nval_new = c(-85239, -85239, -85239, -85239, -8835, -8835, -8732, -8732, 1, 1, 1),
  keep = c(27841, NA, NA, NA, 30447, NA, 32289, NA, 54701, NA, NA)
)

# Create a function to concatenate the GID values
concatenate_GID <- function(keep, GID) {
  if (!is.na(keep)) {
    idx <- which(!is.na(GID) & is.na(lead(keep)))
    if (length(idx) > 0) {
      paste(GID[idx], collapse = "; ")
    } else {
      NA_character_
    }
  } else {
    NA_character_
  }
}

# Apply the function to create the 'merges' column
dt <- dt %>%
  mutate(merges = mapply(concatenate_GID, keep, GID))
```

the result you get is

[image]

Comment: What IDE is this?